# Testing rails routes: can't find ActionController::Assertions::RoutingAssertions methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, routes, integration-testing

I'm trying to test the routes on my rails 2.3.4 application. There are several sites that explain how to test routes, including the rails docs, but I'm getting errors following the instructions.

First, I'm assuming that these tests can be done in related unit test files. There seems to be no more obvious place, and none of the docs specify.

That said, this is a condensed version of `test/unit/TitlesTest.rb`

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class TitleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  # include ActionController::Assertions::RoutingAssertions

  def test_routes
    assert_routing "games", { :controller => "titles", :section => "games", :action => "index", :id => nil }
  end
end
```

`rake test:units` fails with the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assert_routing' for #<TitleTest:0x7f387232ec98>
    /test/unit/title_test.rb:7:in `test_routes'
```

I saw in the Rails API that assert_routing is defined in `ActionController::Assertions::RoutingAssertions`, so I attempted to include that module, only to have it fail elsewhere.

Note the commented `include` line in the code example above.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `clean_backtrace' for #<TitleTest:0x7fd895fadf00>
    /test/unit/title_test.rb:7:in `test_routes'
```

`clean_backtrace` is another testing method defined in ActionController::TestCase::Assertions.

I'm not getting any google search results for these errors - no one else seems to be having this problem. The problem also occurs if I recreate the scenario in a freshly generated rails app. I don't think I should be having to include these modules in my test cases. What might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried including ActionController::TestCase::Assertions?

Comment: After including ActionController::TestCase::Assertions, it seems to work.  I don't think it's normal that I should have to add these includes though.

Comment: I also tried inheriting from ActiveSupport::TestCase instead of Test::Unit::TestCase, but I still need the manual includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a list of [upgrading Rails gotchas](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805595/rails-2-3-2-upgrade-gotchas) on Giant Robots. Apparently your routing test should use class `ActionController::TestCase`, not `ActiveSupport::TestCase`.

Comment: This appears to work in Rails 3 as well, which, sadly, also omits this information from the guides

Answer (score 5):

Routing tests should be done as part of integration tests.

These can be generated using `script/generate script/generate integration_test routes`

An example:

```
class RoutesTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  def test_resources_route
    assert_routing "titles/15", { :controller => "titles", :action => "show", :id => "15" }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is actually a super awesome answer for anyone looking for how to test rails routes

Answer (score 0):

Your routing unit test file has to include the `ActionController::Assertions::RoutingAssertions` module since Rails 2.3.2.